# Determining a Common Substring

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given two strings, determine if they share a common substring. A substring may be as small as one character.

Example:

```
s1 = "and"
s2 = "art"
```

They share the character "a". Then return a string: either YES or NO

```
def twoStrings(s1, s2):
    UniqueChar_S1 = (char for char in s1)
    UniqueChar_S2 = (char for char in s2)

    SubStringExists = False
    for i in set(UniqueChar_S1):
        if i in set(UniqueChar_S2):
            SubStringExists = True
            break
        else:
            continue

    return "YES"*int(SubStringExists) + "NO"*(1 - int(SubStringExists))

def main():
    q = int(input())

    for q_itr in range(q):
        s1 = input()

        s2 = input()

        result = twoStrings(s1, s2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example input:

```
4
wouldyoulikefries
abcabcabcabcabcabc
hackerrankcommunity
cdecdecdecde
jackandjill
wentupthehill
writetoyourparents
fghmqzldbc
```

Expected Output:

```
NO
YES
YES
NO
```

Example Input that Fails:

```
2
aardvark
apple
beetroot
sandals
```

Im not getting thrown an error and so im unsure what is the issue with my code, I cannot see any issues with the code and so Im wondering if anyone can point anything out for me. Also any improvements will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you don't want to use regular expressions... (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to modify your code as following as it is more optimised:

```
def twoStrings(s1, s2):
    UniqueChar_S1 = set(s1)
    UniqueChar_S2 = set(s2)

    for i in UniqueChar_S1:
        if i in UniqueChar_S2:
            return "YES"
 
    return "NO"
```

Comment: Far simpler, however still provides incorrect output in some cases.
For Example:
`2
hello
world
hi
world`

Comment: What does it provide as output? @Jack

Comment: Output is:
NO
NO

Comment: @Jack I would Like to invite you to a chatrooom : [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229832/question-discussion)

Comment: @Jack This is because output in my case works fine

Answer (score 1):

In its simplest form:  `"NO" if set(s1).isdisjoint(s2) else "YES"`

Comment: Hi. Just out of curiousity. Is there a reason you chose `isdisjoint` instead of `intersection`?

Comment: isdisoint will exit on the first match so it doesn't need to build a resulting intersection set.  The function also doesn't require s2 to be converted to a set at all.  So if you have two sets of 100 identical elements, intersection would need to go through all of s2 to build a 100 element set before returning whereas isdisjoint would only need to read one element from s2

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your time and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
def two_strings(s1, s2):
    return "YES" if set(s1).intersection(set(s2)) else "NO"


def main():
    q = int(input("Numbers: "))
    for q_itr in range(q):
        s1 = input("String 1: ")
        s2 = input("String 2: ")

        result = two_strings(s1, s2)
        print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

UniqueChar_S1 = (char for char in s1) is a generator.

```
for i in set(UniqueChar_S1):
    if i in set(UniqueChar_S2):
```

So after checking the 'if' condition once the value of set(UniqueChar_S2) would be empty for second iteration.

So i suggest you the following code:

```
def twoStrings(s1, s2):
    SubStringExists = set(s1)&set(s2)
    return "YES" if SubStringExists else "NO"
```